# Conditional rendering with dmustache

Tags: delphi, mustache, mormot

I'm using dmustache (https://github.com/synopse/dmustache) to render some templates. I wonder how one could not render a certain part if the string-variable is an empty string.

This simplified program renders `FirstName: Joe MiddleName:  LastName: Doe` but I'd like to have `FirstName: Joe LastName: Doe` as there is no MiddleName (and only in that case).

```
program P;

uses
  System.SysUtils, SynMustache, SynCommons;

const
  TEMPLATE = 'FirstName: {{FIRSTNAME}} {{#MIDDLENAME}}MiddleName: {{MIDDLENAME}}{{/MIDDLENAME}} LastName: {{LASTNAME}}';
var
  Mustache: TSynMustache;
  Content: Variant;
begin
  Mustache := TSynMustache.Parse(TEMPLATE);
  TDocVariant.New(Content);
  Content.FirstName := 'Joe';
  Content.MiddleName := '';
  Content.LastName := 'Doe';
  WriteLn(Mustache.Render(Content));
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Using a section in the template doesn't change the outcome

```
TEMPLATE = 'FirstName: {{FIRSTNAME}} {{#MIDDLENAME}}MiddleName: {{MIDDLENAME}} {{/MIDDLENAME}}LastName: {{LASTNAME}}';
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found two ways to solve this. First is using a conditional in the template, like

```
TEMPLATE = 'FirstName: {{FIRSTNAME}} {{#if MIDDLENAME <> ""}}MiddleName: {{MIDDLENAME}} {{/if}}LastName: {{LASTNAME}}';
```

For this to work one also has to pass the Standard Helpers to call to Render, like

```
Mustache.Render(Content, nil, TSynMustache.HelpersGetStandardList)
```

The second is setting the content variable to NULL instead of an empty string (or not at all) and using a section (note the `{{.}}` to self reference inside the section)

```
const
  TEMPLATE = 'FirstName: {{FIRSTNAME}} {{#MIDDLENAME}}MiddleName: {{.}} {{/MIDDLENAME}}LastName: {{LASTNAME}}';
var
  Mustache: TSynMustache;
  Content: Variant;
begin
  Mustache := TSynMustache.Parse(TEMPLATE);
  TDocVariant.New(Content);
  Content.FirstName := 'Joe';
  Content.MiddleName := NULL; //you can also comment this line
  Content.LastName := 'Doe';
  WriteLn(Mustache.Render(Content));
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Comment: Mustache supposed to be logic-less and data-driven. I think it means that right way not to render data is not include it into content. As we can see from the comment in your code, you already know it :)
SynMustache is nice lib, but i prefer RenderJSON over Render (we can generate JSON with full type control, it is easier/more predictable if you want to save it to log, easier to check in debug time etc).